# Text Input Boxes very small in IE but not firefox

Tags: html

I am testing some elements for use in a web page and when using text input boxes it displays correctly in Firefox but when I looked at it in IE the text boxes were unreadably small.
I have linked screeenshots to more clearly explain what I am talking about.
Any ideas why?

[Text Boxes in IE](http://renraku.bravehost.com/images/textboxesinie.jpg)

[Text Boxes in Firefox](http://renraku.bravehost.com/images/textboxesinfirefox.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. I assume you just used:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="" />
```

?

If so, it must have something to do with your CSS file because the HTML will never change.
Try opening your page in Firefox and use FireBug to see the layout properties of the textbox. I guess somewhere you set the font-size to something really small.

Often there are inconsistencies between FireFox, Chrome and (mostly) IE in the way they interpret CSS tags.

It could help if you'd post a link to your webpage so we could check your HTML/CSS code.

Comment: Hi, A test page with the css file linked can be found here [link](http://renraku.bravehost.com/blank2.html)